# Why can't Azure find the provisioning configuration within a PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, provisioning, piping

I'm attempting to deploy an Azure VM using the PowerShell command below, and I'm receiving an unhelpful error.

Something is blocking Azure from recognizing the provisioning configuration.

I also removed the Antimalware JSON entirely from the command and tested, but it made no difference - so at least I know it's not an issue with all of the escaped quotation marks.

Note: this is executed all on one line - I added line breaks for readability on StackOverflow.

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "TestVM" -Label "TestVM" -InstanceSize "extra small" -HostCaching "ReadWrite" -AvailabilitySetName "TestAvailabilitySet" -ImageName "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201412.01-en.us-127GB.vhd" -MediaLocation "https://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/TestDisk.vhd" -DiskLabel "TestDisk"
| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows –Password "xxxxxxxx" -ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon -NoRDPEndpoint -NoWinRMEndpoint -TimeZone "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
| Set-AzureVMMicrosoftAntimalwareExtension -AntimalwareConfiguration "{ `"AntimalwareEnabled`": true, `"RealtimeProtectionEnabled`": true, `"ScheduledScanSettings`": { `"isEnabled`": true, `"day`": 1, `"time`": 120, `"scanType`": `"Full`" } }"
| Set-AzureSubnet –SubnetNames "TestSubnet"
| Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress "x.x.x.x"
| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "TestService" -DeploymentLabel "TestDeployment" -DeploymentName "TestDeployment" -VNetName "TestNetwork"
```

This is the error message that is displayed:

```
New-AzureVM : Virtual Machine TestVM is missing provisioning configuration
At line:1 char:829
+ New-AzureVMConfig -Name "TestVM" -Label "TestVM" -InstanceSize "extra  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureVM], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered several issues:

1) The `Add-AzureProvisioningConfig` command apparently requires the `-AdminUsername` argument, which I had omitted based on older (legacy) examples I found on the internet.

2) The `-ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon` flag is deprecated, and the command would not proceed until I removed it. Again, apparently I've been reading too many tutorials that are old and irrelevant.

3) The VM size should be `ExtraSmall` not `extra small`

The final command that worked, looked like this:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "TestVM" -Label "TestVM" -InstanceSize "ExtraSmall" -HostCaching "ReadWrite" -AvailabilitySetName "TestAvailabilitySet" -ImageName "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201412.01-en.us-127GB.vhd" -MediaLocation "https://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/TestDisk.vhd" -DiskLabel "TestDisk"
| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername "LocalAdmin" –Password "xxxxxxxx" -NoRDPEndpoint -NoWinRMEndpoint -TimeZone "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
| Set-AzureVMMicrosoftAntimalwareExtension -AntimalwareConfiguration "{ `"AntimalwareEnabled`": true, `"RealtimeProtectionEnabled`": true, `"ScheduledScanSettings`": { `"isEnabled`": true, `"day`": 1, `"time`": 120, `"scanType`": `"Full`" } }"
| Set-AzureSubnet –SubnetNames "TestSubnet"
| Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress "x.x.x.x"
| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "TestService" -DeploymentLabel "TestDeployment" -DeploymentName "TestDeployment" -VNetName "TestNetwork"
```